# SQL state [null]; error code [0]; ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement with jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

I am facing exception while executing following query from jdbcTemplate

```
update TEMP_BRD_STATS SET STATS=null WHERE BRDC_STAT_ID=?
```

and following is the exception

> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [update
>   TEMP_BRD_STATS SET STATS=null WHERE BRDC_STAT_ID=?]; SQL state [null];
>   error code [0]; ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

**Where TEMP_BRD_STATS is my table name STATS and BRDC_STAT_ID are column in my table**

**Note : - null is allowed for STATS column**

However I can successfully execute the query in sql developer by providing valid BRDC_STAT_ID column value.

e.g.

```
update TEMP_BRD_STATS SET STATS=null WHERE BRDC_STAT_ID=523;
```

Edit: Following is the JAVA code

```
result = this.jdbcTemplate.query("update TEMP_BRD_STATS SET STATS=null WHERE BRDC_STAT_ID=?",  new Object[] {523}, new QueryResultSetExtractor());
```

Column value is getting changed after executing above code although exception is thrown.

Suppose my column STATS is having 'SUCCESS' value and after executing above java code value is getting changed to null but still it is throwing exception. kind of weird scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter `?` evidently is not filled in. Maybe some parameter like:

```
new Object[] { brdStatId }
```

In general JDBC it could have been using not the `PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()` but the base class version `Statement.executeUpdate(String sql)`.

---

***After code added in question:***

Ah, *query* (SELECT) and *update* (INSERT/UPDATE) mixed up:

```
this.jdbcTemplate.update("update TEMP_BRD_STATS SET STATS=null WHERE BRDC_STAT_ID=?", 523);
```

Comment: Added to answer, if I am right, the error message is quite misleading.

Comment: So i should use this.jdbcTemplate.update() instead of this.jdbcTemplate.query() ?

Comment: Yes, this is also valid for immediate JDBC calls: `int executeUpdate()` instead of `ResultSet executeQuery()`.